# Can we distribute workloads to multiple OS within the same network in Incredibuild?

Tags: distributed-system, incredibuild

I wanted to know if we can distribute our workloads to multiple OS within the same network in Incredibuild? For example, suppose I have installed the Incredibuild coordinator on Windows machine. Can I install an Incredibuild agent on a Linux machine and connect it to the coordinator?

Or all the machines within the network participating in the Incredibuild distribution needs to have the same type of Operating System?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptor before using a tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot connect Linux agent to a Windows coordinator (or vice versa).

The only “mixed” option is with the Linux solution, where you can install Incredibuild Agents on WSL environments, however, the Coordinator itself must be installed on standard Linux machines.